# Field of View dissapears away from spawn

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a field of view function in my game. And it works right next to spawn but when I get farther away from 0,0,0 it just disappears from the game view. If I look at the scene view it's still there it doesn't show up only on the game view. Does anyone know what the problem might be.

Here's the code I'm using.

````
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class VissionEffect : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject localPlayer;
    Mesh mesh;
    public LayerMask layer;
    Vector3 origin = Vector3.zero;
    float startingAngle;
    float fov;
    void Start()
    {
        mesh = new Mesh();
        localPlayer = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("localPlayer");
        GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;

    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        fov = 90f;
        int rayCount = 30;
        float angle = startingAngle;
        float angleInclrease = fov / rayCount;
        float viewDis = 10f;

        Vector3[] verteces = new Vector3[rayCount + 1 + 1];
        Vector2[] uv = new Vector2[verteces.Length];
        int[] triangles = new int[rayCount * 3];

        verteces[0] = origin;

        int vertexIndex = 1;
        int triangleIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= rayCount; i++)
        {
            Vector3 vertex;
            RaycastHit2D ray = Physics2D.Raycast(origin, GetVectorFromAngle(angle), viewDis,layer);

            if(ray.collider == null)
            { 
            vertex = origin + GetVectorFromAngle(angle)  * viewDis;
            }
            else
            {
                vertex = ray.point;
            }
            
            verteces[vertexIndex] = vertex;

            if (i > 0)
            {
                triangles[triangleIndex + 0] = 0;
                triangles[triangleIndex + 1] = vertexIndex - 1;
                triangles[triangleIndex + 2] = vertexIndex;
                triangleIndex += 3;
            }
            vertexIndex++;
            angle -= angleInclrease;
        }
        mesh.vertices = verteces;
        mesh.uv = uv;
        mesh.triangles = triangles;
        

    }

    public static Vector3 GetVectorFromAngle(float angle)
    {
        float angleRad = angle * (Mathf.PI / 180);
        return new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(angleRad), Mathf.Sin(angleRad));
    }

    public static float GetAngleFromVector3(Vector3 dir)
    {
        dir = dir.normalized;
        float n = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        if (n < 0) n += 360;
        return n;
    }

    public void SetOrigin(Vector3 origin)
    {
        this.origin = origin;
    }

    public void SetAimDirection(Vector3 aimDirection)
    {
        startingAngle = (GetAngleFromVector3(aimDirection) - fov / 2) + 90;
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ray.point` you are getting is in **world space** while the mesh vertices are always in **local space**!

You would rather need to convert the optained positions into local space e.g. using [`Transform.InverseTransformPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformPoint.html)

```
for(var i = 0; i < verteces.Length; i++)
{
    verteces[i] =  transform.InverseTransformPoint(verteces[i]);
}
```

Also you are always shooting the ray from

```
Physics2D.Raycast(origin, GetVectorFromAngle(angle), viewDis, layer);
```

where as far as I can tell the `origin` is always `Vector3.zero`.

You probably would rather shoot from the `transform.position`.

(Just btw, the plural of "vertex" is "vertices" ;) )